# jQuery style switcher with cookie

Tags: jquery, css

I don't have much experience with JavaScript but I'm getting into jQuery and learning along the way. I have a style sheet switcher (or theme switcher) on my page, but it switches to the default stylesheet on refresh/visiting a different page.

I know cookies are used for this, but don't know how to implement it into my code...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/light-theme.css"> (in my head tag, html)

jQuery:
$('#dark').click(function (){
   $('link[href="css/light-theme.css"]').attr('href','css/dark-theme.css');
});
$('#light').click(function (){
   $('link[href="css/dark-theme.css"]').attr('href','css/light-theme.css');
});
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can do it with cookies, but i'll try it with HTML5 local storage

jQuery:

```
$('#dark').click(function (){
   $('link[href="css/light-theme.css"]').attr('href','css/dark-theme.css');
   localStorage.stylesheet = 'css/dark-theme.css';
});
$('#light').click(function (){
   $('link[href="css/dark-theme.css"]').attr('href','css/light-theme.css');
   localStorage.stylesheet = 'css/light-theme.css';
});
```

Not sure if you have to wait for document ready or not in order to access the stylesheet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if(localStorage.stylesheet !== null){
         //check which stylesheet is active
         if($('link[href="css/dark-theme.css"]').length>0){
               $('link[href="css/dark-theme.css"]').attr('href',localStorage.stylesheet);
         }else if($('link[href="css/light-theme.css"]').length>0){
               $('link[href="css/dark-theme.css"]').attr('href',localStorage.stylesheet);
         }

    }
})
```

You'll have better browser compatibility with cookies though. The browser may not support localStorage.

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```